# Expanding/Collapsing Multiple HTML tables individually

Tags: c#, javascript, html, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to display a master detail report on a webpage. The way it works now is that I am creating a table to create each master row and then under each master row is another table containing the details. Some of these tables are multiple rows. How would I go about making the detail rows expand/collapse? Here is my code for the detail row:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Bar Code &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            Start Time
        </th>
        <th>
            Length &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            End Time
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id = '@ViewBag.i'>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.BarCode
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.StartTime
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Length
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.EndTime
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In this, the viewBag is being incremented each time the loop to generate this table in the other view is run. I've tried some code before but the closest I could get was an expand/collapse that only affected the first detail table. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you willing to use jQuery?  or do you want a pure javascript method.

Comment: I'm open to any solution. jQuery would be fine.

Comment: <tr id=MasterRow onclick='return toggleDiv( $(this).next(table.detailRow);'> ...I think we will have to do something similar to this but If you paste some more relating code or a JSfiddle then we might get a more clear picture..

Comment: I assume this is something close to what you want http://jsfiddle.net/xwP62/1/? Just click on the table head.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that and when I click the header it does nothing. The reason I am having to name the table with ViewBag is because there are hundreds of rows and that number could change. Would replacing the id with @(ViewBag.i) be causing any problems?

Comment: Not if you ensure that the `table` is passing the correct id as argument with `onclick`. So, if a `table`'s  child `tbody` has the id '@ViewBag.i`, just ensure that the table opening tag looks like `<table onclick="toggleTableTBodyDisplay('@ViewBag.i')">`.

Comment: I fixed that, I had name the tbody wrong. However when I click any table that should collapse, only the first table does.

Comment: It seems that all the other `table`'s `onclick` passes as argument only the id of the first `table`'s child `tbody`. If you can check and ensure that the id passed as argument in each `table`'s `onclick` is the same as the id of **that** `table`'s child `tbody`, it should work.

Comment: After playing with it, that seems to be the case. The issue seems to be that ViewBag isn't being passed. Is there anyway to make that work or to create another variable in the HTML to iterate whenever this part of the loop is run?

Answer (score -1):

[This example](http://jsfiddle.net/etRRk/1/) sounds like the end result that you are looking for.

So basically it sounds like you just need to use `@ViewBag.i` to make each table unique.  Like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Bar Code &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            Start Time
        </th>
        <th>
            Length &nbsp;
        </th>
        <th>
            End Time
        </th>
    </tr>

    <tbody id = 'someTbodyID_@(ViewBag.i)'>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.BarCode
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.StartTime
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.Length
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.EndTime
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<a href="#" id="clicker_@(ViewBag.i)">click me to collapse 1</a>
```

Then in js, with jQuery included:

```
$(function(){
    $("#clicker_@(ViewBag.i)").click(  function(){
        $("#someTbodyID_@(ViewBag.i) tr").toggle();
    });        
});​
```

This will use the `@(ViewBag.i)`  to make each table unique and provide something to click on to collapse all the `TR` within that tbody.

I wasn't sure what you wanted to use as the thing to click on to collapse, so I just added that `A`.  You can add the click event to anything though.

Comment: I realized that you meant expand/collapse, so I changed my code from just `hide()` to `toggle()`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. When I try to use that, the link shows up but doesn't do anything. I'm might be implementing the jQuery wrong though. I'm still pretty new to it. Here is my code:

Comment: <a href="#" id="clicker_@(ViewBag.i)">click me to collapse 1</a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js">
    $(function () {
        $("#clicker_@(ViewBag.i)").click(function () {
            $("#someTbodyID_@(ViewBag.i) tr").hide();
        });
    });
</script>

Comment: Verify that you have jQuery properly included.  Make sure that you have something like this in your HEAD:  


`<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script>`

Comment: Also, check your "Developer Tools Console" to see if there are any errors.

Comment: I made that change and get a different error. But I think I know it and it's probably related to this next problem. When I look at the source the tables are called "someTbodyID_" It looks like ViewBag isn't getting passed.

Comment: -1: Use class names instead of awkward view bindings. Also, you could simply write `$(this).previous()` to get a reference to the table in the click handler of the link. So it would be `$(this).previous().find("tbody").toggle();` No bindings necessary.

Comment: Wouldn't giving it class names not solve my problem of needing to expand/collapse individual tables?

Answer (score -1):

I think you can do this with this code in javascipt:

```
function showHide(obj){  
var tbody = obj.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("someTbodyID_@(ViewBag.i)")[0];  
var old = tbody.style.display;  
tbody.style.display = (old == "none"?"":"none");  
}
```